# Material appears flat in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, append

The material preview looks awesome, however the viewport render looks terrible
I got the material online and appended it. The mesh is UV Mapped. What am I missing?

[image: render v. material preview]

[image: nodes]

Comment: maybe emitter in environment (light source)?

Comment: Probably the mysterious step you are missing is lighting the scene so that you get to see the properties of your material. The preview window does not generate an image that is accurate to the lighting of the scene

Comment: Posted an answer, let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three main steps to any 3D project, you have **Modeling** where you create the actual geometry and polygonal detail. You have **Shading**, which is creating the materials/shaders, and then you have **Lighting** which defines how all the previous parts interact to make a final image.

I think your issue in this instance is you have an object (modeling) and a material (shading) but your lighting is off. Here is an example:

Here the lamp is one unit from the surface of the plane, light has a sharp falloff and is very bright.

[image]

Here is the exact same scene, with the same lamp moved up one unit. The falloff is much softer and any reflections and shadows will be softer as well.

[image]

Based on these examples, it is easy to see that the position of your lamps is very critical to how your scene will end up even if your modeling and shading is perfect. Sadly lighting is a very in-depth topic and isn't really within the scope of this site, but feel free to check some of the linked references below.

---

Helpful links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgAySB7DoOc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-N149FMlWk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o0PauhFQyo

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I watched the tutorials and played with the lighting, but still can not seem to get anywhere near the preview.  I guess this is just a part of the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Your background is a light gray. Try making it darker and moving around the light sources.

If you want realistic lighting, research HDRs. An HDR is a 360 panorama image. You can use one as the world texture and adjust the background strength to change its brightness.